# IIS rewrite URL with extesion to clean URL

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I have the following URLs:

> `https://blog.test.com/search.aspx`

and:

> `https://blog.test.com/post/2017/01/BlogPostNumberOne.aspx`

**Want I want to do:**
Rewrite the URLs which contain the word `post` and have the `aspx` at the end to a clean URL without extension. So for example:

> `https://blog.test.com/search.aspx`
>
> -> **NO PATTERN MATCH**, DO NOTHING
>
> `https://blog.test.com/post/2017/01/BlogPostNumberOne.aspx`
>
> -> **MATCH**, Rewrite to `https://blog.test.com/post/2017/01/BlogPostNumberOne`

I tried the following regex: `^(?=.*/post/)(?=.*aspx$)` and my web.config looks like this:

```
<rule name="Redirect to clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^(?=.*/post/)(?=.*aspx$)" ignoreCase="true"/>
     <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

It is not working at all and sometimes it returns a 500. Do you have any idea how to rewirte my incoming requests properly?

Thx :)

Comment: It does not work because you only use zero-width assertions with no capturing group that you reference in the `{R:1}` replacement. Change the regex to `url="^(.*/post/.*)\.aspx$"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because you only use zero-width assertions with no capturing group that you reference in the `{R:1}` replacement. Change the pattern to a consuming one:

```
url="^((?:.*/)?post/.*)\.aspx$"
      |               |
      |---  R : 1  ---|
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZFXflf/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string input
- `((?:.*/)?post/.*)` - Group 1 capturing a sequence of:

  - `(?:.*/)?` - an optional group matching any 0+ chars other than line break symbols as many as possible up to the last `/` and including it
  - `post/`  - literal char sequence `/post/` (so, the string input should start either with `post/` or anything up to and including `/post/`)
  - `.*`  - any 0+ chars other than line break symbols as many as possible
- `\.aspx` - a literal char sequence `.aspx`
- `$` -  end of string input.

Comment: It works for URLs without the "post" in it. But when I type https://blog.test.com/post/2016/12/23/Blog-Post-Number-One.aspx nothing happends and it doesnt rewrite it without .aspx

Comment: It must be the problem with what string input is passed to the regex engine. Try `url="^((?:.*/)?post/.*)\.aspx$"`. Note the regex  actually *requires* the `post` subpath to be present in the string. It cannot match other URLs that have no `/part/` in them.

Comment: that worked, can u update your answer? I'll mark it with the green checkmark. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, the initial `/` after the host part is not passed to the regex engine, so, the `.*/` must be wrapped up with an optional group, that is better used as a non-capturing one.